# Use of undeclared type 'KIFTestActor'

Tags: ios, swift, kif

I've a code example project, https://github.com/tutsplus/UIAutomation-Jumblify.git, that I've been trying to add automated tests (for practicing purpose since I'm new to the iOS Automation world), and I've followed the instructions on the README, and when I build, I'm getting this error:
[image: buildswifterror1]

This is the project structure, in which you'll find the header file

[image: swifterror2]

Is there any other configuration that I need to do? I've followed the CocoaPods steps, can the above project and my swift UI Test live together?
As I said, I'm a newbie to Swift and automation on IOS!

Please help!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well I was missing the 'Objective-C Bridging Header [image]'